# Android Mobile Backend App works until I export it - raises a GoogleAuthIOException

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My app is based on the Mobile Back-end Starter and works great when I debug on my device in Eclipse or just copy the apk from the project folder directly on to the device.

In order to get the app ready for the play store, I've exported the apk and copied that onto the device. It runs, allows me to pick a Google account but then raises a `GoogleAuthIOException` when I try to do the first query:

```
mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend().listByProperty(...)
```

As part of the export process, I created a keystore/key and signed the app with it. Does this change the authentication to Google in some way? I see lots of stuff on here about Facebook auth breaking when you export an app but I can't find what changes for a Google account login(I'm not using Facebook).

Comment: is your API-key for debug or release ?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm afraid I don't know. I researched this but still am no wiser where to look. Is it the server one on the credentials page of the developer console?

Comment: Ok, check this reference guide https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter-api-reference

Comment: Ok, I have it working. I took the SHA1 fingerprint that was shown at the end of the Eclipse Export Wizard, generated another Android ID from it (in Developers Console/Credentials) and then pasted the new ID into the Mobile Backend Settings page (the appspot.com/admin site).

What occurs to me now is that this admin page only allows one Android ID to be entered at a time and I've just replaced (and probably disabled?) my debug one. Another problem for me to think about but I do have it working, thanks for the pointers.